# Titanium: Unable to access dynamically added TextInput's value on click of a button

Tags: dynamic, titanium, textinput

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
function btnClickedHandler(e){
    alert(nameTi.text);
    alert($.index.nameTi);
}
function addContent(){
    var showBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
        id: "showButton",
        title:"Show Text",
        top: 10,
    });
    var nameTi = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        id:"displayText",
        textFieldId: 'displayText',
        width: 50
    });
    showBtn.addEventListener("click", btnClickedHandler);
    $.index.add(nameTi);
    $.index.add(showBtn);
}
$.index.open();
addContent();
```

Any suggestions to access dynamically added text input. One way could be definitely by storing instance in global variable. But can be done using id like `$("#instanceId")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function addContent(){
    var showBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
        id: "showButton",
        title:"Show Text",
        top: 10,
    });
    var nameTi = Ti.UI.createTextField({
        id:"displayText",
        textFieldId: 'displayText',
        width: 50
    });
    showBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert(nameTi.text);
    alert($.index.nameTi);
   }
});
    $.index.add(nameTi);
    $.index.add(showBtn);
}
$.index.open();
addContent();
```

Comment: That worked...

Just wondering if the handler can be defined outside for easy  code maintenance.